# Object overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am using strong `IBOutlet` to custom `PDFView` in `NSViewController` subclass but I am getting crash on 10.11 after switching view controller. Everything is working fine on 10.8,10.9 and 10.10. I am using ARC.

```
self.activeRootViewController = controller;
self.backgroundWindow.contentView = controller.view;

@property (strong) IBOutlet MYPDFView* pdfView; // property inside NSViewController subclass.
```

> MYPDFView object 0x10ac1bc50 overreleased while already deallocating;
>   break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

I have added breakpoint on `objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error` but unable to solve this issue.

Can anyone please help me out?

`dealloc` method MYPDFView is getting called only once.

Backtrace from lldb:

```
objc[23395]: MYPDFView object 0x10ac1bc50 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
Process 23395 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x11b04b, 0x00007fff926bcb1c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1 2.1
    frame #0: 0x00007fff926bcb1c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error:
->  0x7fff926bcb1c <+0>: retq   
    0x7fff926bcb1d <+1>: nop    

libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_lock:
    0x7fff926bcb1e <+0>: movl   %edi, %eax
    0x7fff926bcb20 <+2>: shrl   $0x9, %eax
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x11b04b, 0x00007fff926bcb1c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1 2.1
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff926bcb1c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error
    frame #1: 0x00007fff926bd78a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::overrelease_error() + 42
    frame #2: 0x00007fff9ad13102 AppKit`-[NSImmediateActionGestureRecognizer dealloc] + 42
    frame #3: 0x00007fff9702ce3c CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM removeAllObjects] + 252
    frame #4: 0x00007fff9a426caf AppKit`-[NSView removeAllGestureRecognizers] + 294
    frame #5: 0x00007fff9a4257b3 AppKit`-[NSView _finalizeWithReferenceCounting] + 1333
    frame #6: 0x00007fff9a425256 AppKit`-[NSView dealloc] + 151
    frame #7: 0x00007fff906ef366 PDFKit`-[PDFView dealloc] + 834
    frame #8: 0x000000010003236d MYApp`-[MYPDFView dealloc] + 125
    frame #9: 0x00007fff926a6094 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 476
    frame #10: 0x00007fff96fc7a72 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
    frame #11: 0x00007fff9c7f30fe Foundation`__NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    frame #12: 0x00007fff970119f4 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    frame #13: 0x00007fff97011683 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
    frame #14: 0x00007fff970111da CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
    frame #15: 0x00007fff970086d1 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1841
    frame #16: 0x00007fff97007d38 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    frame #17: 0x00007fff9517dd55 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    frame #18: 0x00007fff9517da97 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184
    frame #19: 0x00007fff9517d9cf HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    frame #20: 0x00007fff9a433f3a AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 1067
    frame #21: 0x00007fff9a433369 AppKit`-[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
    frame #22: 0x00007fff9a427ecc AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 682
    frame #23: 0x00007fff9a3f1162 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 1176
    frame #24: 0x0000000100003452 MYApp`main + 34
    frame #25: 0x00007fff8eecc5ad libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #26: 0x00007fff8eecc5ad libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: I wonder whether Instruments with the Allocations template would show you anything useful about the retain/release history of that object.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for suggestion. Everything looks fine in allocation. # persistent = 1 # Transient = 2 #total =3  (Released object 2 times)

Comment: Why you set `@property (strong) IBOutlet MYPDFView* pdfView; ` ? `strong`? How about `weak`?

Comment: @anhtu The current recommended best practice from Apple is for IBOutlets to be strong unless weak is specifically needed to avoid a retain cycle.

Comment: @ParagBafna https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html - "Outlets should generally be weak". Can you please give me the link where "The current recommended". I did't update the docs. Thank you

Comment: And can you show more code about `MYPDFView* pdfView`, what do you do with it? ...

Comment: @anhtu Documentation is old. From "Implementing UI Designs in Interface Builder" session from WWDC2015(32:30)
And the last option I want to point out is the storage type, which can either be strong or weak. In general you should make your outlet strong, especially if you are connecting an outlet to a subview or to a constraint that's not always going to be retained by the view hierarchy. The only time you really need to make an outlet weak is if you have a custom view that references something back up the view hierarchy and in general that's not recommended.

Comment: @ParagBafna thank you very much